# How to execute object-dependent methods?

Tags: java, oop

I'm having a `Canvas` with several `Shape` objects. The objects are selectable, and are tracked in `lastSelection` and `currentSelection`.

On shift+click, I want to connect some of the `Shapes` by a line. But for each `Shape` implementation, the way a connection is made should be different.

How can I rewrite the following and getting rid of 1) instanceof checks, 2) typecasts?

```
class Shape;
class Ellipse extends Shape;
class Line extends Shape;
class Square extends Shape;
//some more

Shape lastSelection;
Shape currentSelection;

onClick() {
    if (lastSelection instanceof Ellipse && currentSelection instanceof Ellipse) {
        connect((Ellipse) lastSelection, (Ellipse) currentSelection);
    }
    if (lastSelection instanceof Square && currentSelection instanceof Square) {
        connect((Square) lastSelection, (Square) currentSelection);
    }
    //some more
}


connect(Ellipse e1, Ellipse 2) {}
connect(Square s1, Square s2) {}
```

Comment: Is this the actual Java code? Looks like half baked algorithm to me.

Comment: You could have a `connect(Shape other)` method on your shape class - it depends what the connection depends on, the type of the connector or the type of the connectee or both.

Comment: Then I would still have to do `instanceof` checks inside the `connect()` method if eg I only want `Ellipses` to be connected with `Ellipses`, not with other objects... plus empty `connect()` methods for `Shapes` that should not be connectable at all.